# FQL get last 50 photos query returns error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can i get the last 50 photos uploaded by all my friends ?

I try to run this query in FQL:

```
SELECT pid, src 
FROM photo 
WHERE 
owner IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me())
OR pid IN (
     SELECT pid FROM photo_tag 
     WHERE subject in (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me())
) 
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

I need to get last 50 photos from all my friends or that my friends where tagged in...

when i run it in the API Explorer i get an error:

```
{
  "error": "Request failed"
}
```

I know i have sufficen permission becus when i run these 2 query i get results:

```
SELECT pid, src FROM photo WHERE owner =(me())
```

and

```
SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()
```

EDIT:
I have also tried this ..

```
SELECT pid, caption, aid, owner, link, src_big, src_small, created, modified FROM photo 
WHERE owner IN  ( SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me() )
and created >= 1377800559 
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 100
```

how can i get more information ?
is it not possible to run such a query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly !!! Last Posted Photos from all friends...

```
SELECT pid, src, src_small, src_big, target_id, created, backdated_time 
FROM photo where pid in (
    SELECT attachment.media.photo.pid
    FROM stream 
    WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me()) AND type = 247
)
```

as you can see my initial approach was all wrong ... 
it is actually required to use the `stream` table to get the latest posts..
then it could be filtered to get only photos posted and use their `pid` to get all the required info !!! YAY!

I hope it helps other that encounter the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but a weird thing is happening here. When I tried your query- I got

> Request failed

Then, after digging a bit I replaced `SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()` with the IDs and the query worked!

So, as a solution you could first try to get the list of friends with :

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
```

Then use this result in your query as-

```
SELECT pid, src 
FROM photo 
WHERE 
  owner IN (ID1, ID2, ID3 ...)
  OR pid IN (
     SELECT pid FROM photo_tag 
     WHERE subject IN (ID1, ID2, ID3 ...)
  ) 
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Strange, but this'll work!

Comment: have you tried it for the IDs of all your friends ? people might have a lot of friends i i wonder if there is a character limit to an FQL query...

Comment: Sorry, just tried it with the IDs of all my friends and the query seems to return "Request Failed" guess there is a limit but its nor character limit.. any other idea of how can i get top 50 recent photos?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't simply timing out? you're requesting a lot of expensive data to fetch

Comment: @Mortalus, you can try with giving the user ids in chunks; and then select the latest 50 from the whole lot. Since, there seems no other option.

Comment: @Shadowfax this is a bad idea as i have found that it will take only 4 user ids per query and sometimes even less ... so give an average of 400 friend it will take 100 iterations of ~7 second that equals 700 sec which is more than 10 minutes .. that is not a reasonable time to wait ...

Comment: Hmm, but I didn't expect a downvote from you. Anyways good luck!

Comment: @Shadowfax I have found a solution (see my answer)... the downvote is due to the answer not working ... it will be misleading for others to see an upvoted answer that does not provide the requirement from the tittle of the question ...